# Unreachable Statement in my Public Boolean Method

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create an isValid method that verifies if a certain date is real or not (i.e. 3/31/2016 is valid, 2/29/2001 is valid since it's a leap year, 2/30/2016 is not valid)

Here is my method public boolean isValid()

`

```
{
   //January
    if (month == 1 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //February
    if (month == 2 && day <= 28) {
            return true;
    }
    else {
        if ((((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100) != 0)) || ((year % 400) == 0)) {
            if (day == 29) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //March
    if (month == 3 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //April
    if (month == 4 && day <= 30) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //May
    if (month == 5 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //June
    if (month == 6 && day <= 30) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //July
    if (month == 7 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //August
    if (month == 8 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //September
    if (month == 9 && day <= 30) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //October
    if (month == 10 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //November
    if (month == 11 && day <= 30) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //December
    if (month == 12 && day <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;

    }

}
```

`

Now, when I compile, it says there are unreachable statements essentially wherever it says "if". Could somebody please help? I've already tried the 'if (true) {return}' method and I can't find anything else helpful.

Comment: 2001 isn't a leap year...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first if statement, it returns regardless of outcome, meaning all the following if statements will never be reached as if your first condition is not met it will return, and if it is, it also returns.

A fix for this is to remove all your else return false paths and string all if statements in an else if chain and then return false at the end of that.

e.g.

```
if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}
return false;
```

Comment: So how exactly can I fix that? Should I create 12 different methods?

Comment: My bad :// shoulda refreshed

Comment: && also has bad effects.

Comment: accept the answer if you are satisfied so people know the question has been resolved :)

Comment: one thing, now it says i'm missing a return statement.

Comment: like I've had return statements all throughout, but do I need one at the end or something?

Comment: thats just java doing its own checks. at the end, instead of doing else { return false} just end it with return false.

Comment: never mind that was a mistake elsewhere that I fixed. It's working fine now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should if elseif elseif elseif... else...

when you say if and else.. your code will end either in if or else.. henceforth other if statements are unreachable...

that is the error you are getting...change other conditions to elseif

Answer (score 0):

**Your code will never go to the second if statement as the else part of first(January's) will terminate your program**

Your code has to be like:

```
if(month == 1)
{
   if(day <= 31)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
if(month==2)
{
  ----
  ----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return **statement should be last statement of any method**
```

else you can use variable instead of direct return statement like

```
public boolean isValid()
{
 boolean status=false;
       if(condition)
          {
              status=true;
          }
    return status;
}
```